# Error inflating class fragment in android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an android application. During development I am facing an a button in a fragment. I developed code like below

```java
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Utility.log("TestMultiAnswerActivity","Start of onCreateView()");
            .....
        multiQuestionAndAnswersFragmentOkButtonIdLocalVariable =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.multiQuestionAndAnswersFragmentOkButtonId);
        Utility.log("TestMultiAnswerActivity","777");
        multiQuestionAndAnswersFragmentOkButtonIdLocalVariable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  readCurrentQuestion();
              }
            });
        Utility.log("TestMultiAnswerActivity","888");
        ....
    }
```

Fragment is declared as

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/multiQuestionAndAnswersFragment"
    android:name="edu.utd.OOADques.TestMultiAnswerActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

When I am running this code I am getting error as

```
11-24 15:09:51.148: I/TestMultiAnswerActivity(22916): Start of onCreateView()
11-24 15:09:51.307: I/TestMultiAnswerActivity(22916): 777
11-24 15:09:51.315: D/AndroidRuntime(22916): Shutting down VM
11-24 15:09:51.315: W/dalvikvm(22916): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.utd.OOADques/edu.utd.OOADques.TestActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class fragment
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class fragment
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at edu.utd.OOADques.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:20)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    ... 11 more
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at edu.utd.OOADques.TestMultiAnswerActivity.onCreateView(TestMultiAnswerActivity.java:63)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:861)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1137)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4746)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
11-24 15:09:51.405: E/AndroidRuntime(22916):    ... 21 more
```

I used similar code in 2 other fragment with out any problem only difference those fragments and this is checkbox. In this fragment I am using checkbox and in those fragment I am using radio button. Can someone please guide with the issue?

I tried other solutions suggested for similar error but none worked.

I am extending fragment (of `android.app.Fragment`).

Comment: What does your code look like at line 63 of `TestMultiAnswerActivity.java`?

Comment: line 63 is 'multiQuestionAndAnswersFragmentOkButtonIdLocalVariable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {'

Comment: It looks like `view.findViewById(R.id.multiQuestionAndAnswersFragmentOkButtonId);` is returning null instead of the button you want. Make sure there is a `Button` element in the view that you're inflating with the id `multiQuestionAndAnswersFragmentOkButtonId`.

Comment: could you please share how you inflate the fragment !?

Comment: @bwegs yes your correct i am getting null for that but dont know why it is like that. there is button element in that view

Comment: code is <Button
          android:id="@+id/multiQuestionAndAnswersFragmentOkButtonId"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/questionAndAnswersFragmentOkButton" />

Comment: found the issue. i was inflating wrong acitivity.

Comment: You had t inflate multiQuestionAndAnswersFragment right?

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest Yes